# ¿Por qué la función plt.grid me crea un fondo gris al graficar mis datos en lugar de solo crear las líneas de cuadrícula? Matplotlib + Python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, depuración, spyder, ciencia-de-datos

Empecé a aprender ciencia de datos y me enseñaron que podía usar `matplotlib.pyplot` para graficar mis datos. Aquí hay una pequeña vista previa de esos (son precios OHLC de un período de tiempo de 1 hora):

[image: A little preview of my SOLUSDT dataframe]

Sucede que solo estoy interesado en trazar el `Close Price` contra la `End Date`, y escribí el siguiente código para hacerlo:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Import the csv file without index
SOLUSDT = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/ResetStoreX/Downloads/Binance futures data/SolUSDT-Mark_Prices_Klines_1h_Timeframe/zip/SOLUSDT-1h-June-29-2021-February-13-2022.csv', index_col=0)

# Create a new df that only contains the date and close price from the previous imported df
SOLUSDT_close = SOLUSDT[['End Date','Close Price']]

# Set the 'Date' column as the actual index
SOLUSDT_close.set_index('End Date', inplace=True) 

# set the breadth and length of the plot as a good mix of values
plt.figure(figsize=(14,5))

# set a grid background to the plot
plt.grid(True) 

# set the color of the trend as blue
plt.plot(SOLUSDT_close, 'b')

# give a title to the plot
plt.title('SOLUSDT close price from June 29 2021 to February 13 2022')

# give a label to the x axis
plt.xlabel('Date')

# gove a label to the y axis
plt.ylabel('Close Price')

# plot it
plt.plot(SOLUSDT_close)
```

Sin embargo, terminé con una siguiente salida que fue simplemente decepcionante:

[image: disappointing output]

Como se puede ver, las líneas de la cuadrícula se fusionaron con un fondo gris, y además no fue mostraron algunos de los valores de `End Date` uno esperaría en el eje x.

Si decido eliminar la declaración `plt.grid(True)` y ejecutar el código nuevamente, termina trazando el siguiente gráfico:

[image: not cool chart]

Lo que me gustaría lograr es trazar un gráfico como este de [CoinGecko](https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/solana) (obviamente ignorando los volúmenes, pero mostrando las líneas de cuadrícula y algunas fechas importantes):

[image: desired chart]

¿Pueden ayudarme?

Comment: Buen día, ¿Estás seguro que no resolviste tu problema al crear la pregunta? Copié y pegué el código y sustituí el `dataframe` con uno de prueba y funciona correctamente. Por cierto, la última linea no la necesitas ya que donde pusiste el comentario `# set the color of the trend as blue` estás dibujando la gráfica y la última línea dibuja la misma gráfica una segunda vez.

Comment: Hola, bueno tuve en cuenta lo de quitar la última línea, pero aún sigo teniendo el mismo problema, creo que el fondo "gris" que se crea tiene que ver con el hecho de que estoy usando 5520 datos, lo que hace me hace pensar que se crea una línea vertical gris para cada uno de ellos, ¿no habrá una forma de decirle a `matplotlib` que sólamente tenga en cuenta 10 o 12 de esos datos para generar esas líneas verticales? @HeytalePazguato

Comment: Acabo de hacer una prueba con 5520 datos y el mismo código que pusiste, funciona correctamente y las etiquetas del eje X se reducen automáticamente a 8 ¿Estás seguro que no resolviste tu problema al crear la pregunta?

Comment: Sucede que un usuario de la comunidad inglesa de stackoverflow mencionó que dado que tenía muchas fechas asociadas a los datos, estas estaban ocasionando que se generaran líneas verticales para cada dato, generando ese fondo gris, este usuario me sugiró usar la sentencia `plt.grid(True, axis='y')` para obtener un resultado aproximado a lo que quiero (líneas horizontales como las mostradas en el gráfico de CoinGecko), respuesta en detalle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72282269/why-is-the-plt-grid-function-setting-a-complete-grey-background-for-my-plotted-d

Comment: Sin embargo, al intentar usar la sentencia `plt.grid(True, axis='x', which='major')` para sólo graficar algunas de las fechas, termino obteniendo el mismo problema inicial, esto último sería lo que me haría falta para solucionar por completo mi problema, el cual no sé cómo manejar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución gracias al usuario [My Work](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12281892/my-work) en esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72282269/why-is-the-plt-grid-function-setting-a-complete-grey-background-for-my-plotted-d?noredirect=1#comment127706049_72282269) que hice en la comunidad inglesa de SO.

Básicamente lo único que tenía que hacer era agregar `parse_dates=['End Date']` dentro de la función `pd.read_csv()` para convertir todos los valores cadena de la columna `End Date` a fechas de tiempo, luego agregar `plt.grid(True, axis ='y')` y `plt.grid(True, axis='x', which='major')` para crear la cuadrícula deseada y poner sólo unas pocas fechas importantes.

**Solución**:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Import the csv file without index
SOLUSDT = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/ResetStoreX/Downloads/Binance futures data/SolUSDT-Mark_Prices_Klines_1h_Timeframe/zip/SOLUSDT-1h-June-29-2021-February-13-2022.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=['End Date'])

# Create a new df that only contains the date and close price from the previous imported df
SOLUSDT_close = SOLUSDT[['End Date','Close Price']]

# Set the 'Date' column as the actual index
SOLUSDT_close.set_index('End Date', inplace=True) 

# set the breadth and length of the plot as a good mix of values
plt.figure(figsize=(14,5))

# set a grid background to the plot
plt.grid(True, axis ='y')
plt.grid(True, axis='x', which='major')

# set the color of the trend as blue
plt.plot(SOLUSDT_close, 'b')

# give a title to the plot
plt.title('SOLUSDT close price from June 29 2021 to February 13 2022')

# give a label to the x axis
plt.xlabel('Date')

# gove a label to the y axis
plt.ylabel('Close Price')
```

**Output**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]